# Laravel : $casts in laravel model not working

Tags: php, laravel

i have column `id_a(varchar , primary key)` with values are 1 - 10. I want to cast that id_a column to integer, so if i execute query `\App\Model\Main::max('id_a');` it returns value 10 same as if i do `SELECT MAX(CAST(id_a as integer)) FROM mains`. I added this code to my model but not working (The \App\Model\Main::max('id_a') still return value 9):

```
protected $casts = [
     'id_a' => 'integer',
 ];
```

and this is the full code of my model :

```
protected $table = 'tb_main';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_a';
public $incrementing = false;

protected $guarded = ['id_a'];

protected $casts = [
     'id_acara' => 'integer',
 ];
```

Comment: The cast should only change a `'10'` to a `10` (string vs int). If you're expecting a 10 and getting a 9 then something else is going on. What is the data type on the column in your db?

Comment: yes it is, and it should be returns 10 if i execute the `\App\Model\Main::max('id_a')` query because the id_a column is already returns int value after i added $casts in model, but i have no idea why it still return 9. The datatype of that column in my db is varchar @jfadich

Comment: The column should be an `INT` not a `VARCHAR`. The `max()` method in eloquent uses the SQL `MAX()` function which I suspect may treat string numbers differently than integers.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$casts` setting isn't going to affect a call like `App\Model\Main::max('id_a')` at all - it's going straight to the database. Same as doing `SELECT MAX(id_a) FROM mains` in SQL.

If you want to use the `id_a` column as an integer, it should be an integer column in the database. The current behavior - sorting `9` as bigger than `10` - means it's a string column.

Comment: okay thanks, i thought by adding $casts, if i call `App\Model\Main::max('id_a')` will do `SELECT MAX(CAST(id_a as integer)) FROM mains` @ceejayoz

Comment: question updated @ceejayoz

Comment: @Janotama No, `$casts` won't change your queries at all, just how it handles the data *from* those queries. If you want that column to be an integer, make it an integer, or take one of the approaches in the duplicate thread.

Comment: i tried it using `DB::table('mains')->value(DB::raw('MAX(CAST(id_a as integer))'))` and it returns value 10, thank you

Comment: @dreamcatcher I'm glad that works. Do note, though, that with thousands or millions of rows, that query will be **very** slow, as it requires a calculation on every row in the database every time you make it.

Comment: Okay sir, thank you for your great advice @ceejayoz